# Laravel- Twilio sms are stuck in queued

Tags: php, sms, twilio, laravel-5.4

I am using [Aloha/Twilio](https://github.com/aloha/laravel-twilio) package with my laravel app to send sms from my application to mobile.

All the configurations are done exactly how they are described in the given link.
When I do

```
$twilio =   new \Aloha\Twilio\Twilio(env('TWILIO_SID'), env('TWILIO_TOKEN'), env('TWILIO_FROM'));
dd($twilio->message('+#########', 'this is test'));
```

the response I am seeing is

```
Services_Twilio_Rest_Message {#285 ▼
  #subresources: array:1 [▶]
  +"client": Services_Twilio {#254 ▶}
  +"sid": "MY SID"
  +"date_created": "Fri, 03 Mar 2017 06:51:11 +0000"
  +"date_updated": "Fri, 03 Mar 2017 06:51:11 +0000"
  +"date_sent": null
  +"account_sid": "ACOUNT SID"
  +"to": "+###########"
  +"from": "+15005550006"
  +"messaging_service_sid": null
  +"body": "Sent from your Twilio trial account - this is test"
  +"status": "queued"
  +"num_segments": "1"
  +"num_media": "0"
  +"direction": "outbound-api"
  +"api_version": "2010-04-01"
  +"price": null
  +"price_unit": "USD"
  +"error_code": null
  +"error_message": null
  +"uri": "/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACe6bc0a30f091bbbcdd33de2a86ad68c8/Messages/SMd3e7591a45754b9db3aa62304a5791a6"
  +"subresource_uris": {#284 ▶}
}
```

I am using the magic number as a `From` number i.e. **+15005550006** to send sms and I am using the app with my test credentials.

All my messages are being shown as `queued` in the status

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

If you are using [test credentials](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/test-credentials) and a magic number then the messages will never be sent. The only way to send the message is to use real credentials and a real number. If you are still on a trial account then you can do this with any number you verify in your Twilio console and the messages won't cost you anything.

Let me know if this helps at all.

Comment: Thanks, It helped. I used real credentials and real number and got the sms